# Wind delay at the British Open

Tags: golf

Currently, the British Open is in the midst of a Wind Delay.

Why is wind a reason enough to cause a delay at any golf course?  Wind is not a dangerous condition like lightning.  Heavy rain, I could even see being a reason to cause a delay because it hinders sight, and could be considered a health hazard.

Wind however only affects the flight of the ball, and would do so for everyone on the course at the same time.  Being able to watch the pros handle the wind would be a benefit for everyone watching.  And if gallery hazard is the concern, then they should be removed from the course.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only reason wind typically causes a delay in a golf tournament is because the ball cannot sit still on the green.

Professional tournament greens are so fast, once the wind gets over about 25 MPH, the wind can actually cause the ball to move.  From a rules standpoint, the problem is if the ball is moved by the wind, it must be played as it lies. In Hawaii two years ago where they encountered similar winds, players with 8 foot putts were having them blown 40 feet off the green.

You just can't play golf when the ball won't sit still on the green.

As a side note, rain is not generally a reason to cancel or delay golf either, unless accompanied by lightning.  However, where heavy rain does cause a delay is when the course becomes so saturated it begins overwhelming the drainage, water begins accumulating and there's no place one can find to play that isn't inundated by casual water.

Comment: Rain also can cause the field to be in a condition where playing on it would damage the course.